# IF a table does not exist, skip in for loop in R

Tags: mysql, r, if-statement

I have series of mysql tables in R as follows. Of the tables, some are missing.

```
     Name
        A
        B
        C
        D
```

namelist<-Name

I have created a function. I have used mapply to run the function across the list

```
 Y<-function(x){summary(x)}
 A<-mapply(Name, Y)
```

This throws an error as follows

```
Table B doesn't exist
```

I have a hundred tables in the list of tables. It is manually impossible to determine all the missing tables. Is there a way to skip over the missing tables using an if statement.

Comment: If R's MySQL API does not already offer a function to check if a table exists, you might have to use some dynamic SQL here.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could run `SHOW TABLES` on the current database to get a list of all tables, and then use that in your R code.

Comment: Yes Thats One way. The alternative is to create the missing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `namelist2` list contains all available tables in MySql using `show tables;` then use `is.element` to check

```
 Y<-function(x){
                 if(is.element(x, namelist2)) summary(x)
    }
```

Another option try `safely` from `purrr`

```
   library(purrr)
   Y<-function(x){
                 safely(summary(x))
    }
```

Or you can try `try or try-catch`

Comment: How does this address the problem that a given table may not exist on the MySQL server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for point that out, I did not read the OP carefully. Just for the records, I did not saw your suggestion `show tables` when I wrote mine. Thanks